# How to locate points on map from shapefile in ggplot (ggmaps)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, ggmap

I want to use the `gglocator()` function from the `ggmaps` package to identify coordinates on a map to position sub-plots. The following example yields an error message.

```
library(maptools)
library(ggmap)

## Get shapefiles for plotting
download.file("http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/geodatafiles/NUTS_2010_60M_SH.zip",paste0(tempdir(),"/NUTS_2010_60M_SH.zip"))
unzip(paste0(tempdir(),"/NUTS_2010_60M_SH.zip"),exdir=tempdir())
eurMap <- readShapePoly(fn=paste0(tempdir(),"/NUTS_2010_60M_SH/data/NUTS_RG_60M_2010"))
eurMapDf <- fortify(eurMap, region='NUTS_ID')

## Create the figure
gg <– ggplot(data=eurMapDf) + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group)) 
gg

## use gglocator()
gglocator()

## >  Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , deparse(mapping$x)) : 
##    undefined columns selected
```

`gglocator()` works fine with the following example which leads me to suspect that the problem is related to the data passed into the plotting function (the shapefile).

```
## gglocator works fine with this example
qmap("National Capital Region", zoom = 11)
gglocator(2)
```

Is there a way to plot shapefiles with ggplot and use `gglocator()` to identify points? If not, is there any alternative locator function I could use? `grid.locator()` doesn't work either as it does not output coordinates in the right units. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

It looks like the `mapping` slot is not always defined when creating the `gg object`. I can make `gglocator()` run by explicitly setting the mapping to the variables of the `data` slot. E.g. the following works:

```
gg$mapping$x  <- substitute(long)
gg$mapping$y <- substitute(lat)
gg

## gglocator() works as expected
gglocator()
```

So I guess my real question is how to ensure that `mapping` is set when calling `ggplot`.

**Update 2**

All works fine when the mapping is provided in the ggplot function call and not as argument to `geom_polygon()`. E.g.

```
gg2 <- ggplot(data=eurMapDf,aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group)) +   geom_polygon() 
gg2

## works fine now
gglocator()
```

I am not sure if there is a reason why mapping needs to be declared in the `ggplot()` call or if this is a bug. Many of the examples found around the web use the syntax I used first (or to put it differently, the syntax I used first was copy-pasted from one of the many examples I found around the web).

Comment: Seeing the example from the ggmap CRAN manual, I did the following. `g <- ggplot() + geom_map(data = mapdf, map = mapdf, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id, group = group), colour = "grey50", size = 0.3);           
g + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)); gglocator(1, xexpand = c(0, 0), yexpand = c(0, 0))` mapdf is your eurMapDf. I ended up receiving the following message. `Error in data[, deparse(mapping$x)] : incorrect number of dimensions`.

Comment: Hmm, so it looks like the error is linked to `mapping` of the gg object.  Running `eurMapDf$mapping` shows that this is an empty list while there is an entry at the below (working) example. However simply replacing the the two does not solve the problem. I have no clue how to figure out the correct x any y values here (yet).